# How to get number of elements in an array in JSON using Groovy script?

Tags: arrays, json, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have a simple json file for an array called "sample.json"

content of sample json:

```
{"apps": ["app1","app3","app3"]}
```

How I can get the size of the array on this JSON file using groovy script. I tried following but no luck,

```
def json_file = readFile("sample.json")
def json_output = readJSON text: json_file
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json_output) 
println json.results.size('apps')
```

Can anyone help me to get the result as size of the array is "3" ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JsonSlurper in pipeline.

readJson  already returns a parsed json.

This should work:

```
def json_file = readFile("sample.json")
def json = readJSON text: json_file
println json.apps.size()
```